# Equivalent of <c:url/> for Velocity

Tags: jsp, velocity

Is there an equivalent of the `<c:url/>` tag (of jsp core taglib fame) for Apache Velocity? I'd like to create urls when I don't always know the path/context root (a la `<c:url value="/mypage"/>`).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [LinkTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/LinkTool.html).

Comment: Would you have an an example of the equivalent way to accomplish `<c:url value="/my-mapping"/>`?